# Can we use sleep(9);Function

Tags: iphone, interface

Can we use sleep function at applicationDidFinishLaunching to take more time to show Splash screen?.Is this Valid in HIG

Comment: A better idea is to not do this. All you will do is make users think your application is really slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sleep function in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, but doing what you want to do is frowned on in the HIG

> Avoid displaying an About window, a splash screen, or providing any other type of startup experience that prevents people from using your application immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But it's really stupid. Also if you don't exit applicationDidFinishLaunching in a certain amount of time (say, 2-10 seconds) your app will be killed by the system.

Comment: The watchdog timer on the iPhone is 20 seconds, at which point your application is killed.  Note that this is disabled when running your application via Xcode, so you won't see this when debugging, only when running independently on the device.

Comment: Yes it's 20 seconds, BUT depending on things you can or can't control, such as how long it takes to actually load your executable and Default.png, you might have somewhat less time in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 0):

I never really understand the view against a splash screen as most apps I run on iPhone and iPad have them.  I see not issue with a company logo on display for 2 - 3 seconds rather than a Default.png that flashes on screen for a nano second leaving the user to wonder "er what was that?"

Nearly all applications have a splash screen either on mobile devices or desktop.  I agree with not delaying the user experience but I also agree with a company logo.

If a user is put off by a 2-3 second delay then they really should go on a "learn to chill" course!